# Right rotation of an array by slicing

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to do an in-place right rotation of an array `nums` `k` times. I can't get my head around why my code works for one array and fails for another.

Code - `nums[:]=nums[-k:]+nums[:k+1]`

Works for `nums=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and `k=3`

Output - `nums=[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Fails for `nums=[-1,-100,3,99]` `k=2`

Output - `[3, 99, -1, -100, 3]`
Desired Output - `[3, 99, -1, -100]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-rotate-a-list/

It says you can rotate right by doing

```
nums=[-1,-100,3,99]
k = 2
nums = nums[-k:] + nums[:-k]
print(nums)
```

The output is `[3, 99, -1, -100]`

Explanation:
First, you take the desired (`k`) number of elements from the right side of the list and place them as the start of the rotated list (`nums[-k:]`). Second, you take the left side of the list and place it at the end of the new list (`nums[:-k]`). This will not work if `k > len(nums)`.

Comment: Good solution thanks, but can you think of why my solution fails?

Comment: @pykam the nums[-k:] works as you expected, but the nums[:k+1] takes one extra item, which causes the problem. The reason it works in your first example is because (i think) 2K+1 = len(nums) to nums[:4] yields exactly the desired items. If you try the same thing with k=2 on the same list you'll see that not all elements are included in the new list

Answer (score 1):

both outputs are logical.

```
#nums[-k:] is [3,99]
#nums[:k+1] is [-1,-100,3]
#Output is [3, 99, -1, -100,3]
```

i think your solution isn't optimal i think this might help you:
[1]: https://www.techiedelight.com/right-rotate-an-array-k-times/

Answer (score 0):

PHP solution:

slice array into 2 parts and merge in reverse order.

```
$c = count($A);
    $a1 = array_splice($A,0,$c - $K );
    $a2 = $A;
    return array_merge($a2,$a1);
```